# How to create two functions with the same name and different return type and runned based on boolean parameter

Tags: c++, function, overloading

I have two functions with the same name but different return types. I want to run the function based on their third parameter. If the third parameter is true I want to run the first and If the parameter is false to run the second function. I was trying different things on my own because I couldn't find information online and I wasn't sure how is this called. Here is what I tried to do:

```
static int function(int a, int b, const bool=true);
static std::string function(int a, int b, const bool=false);
```

I would be grateful if someone can explain how to do this or at least give me a link to some information.

Comment: That's not possible. The return type has to be known at compile time. The value of the parameter is known at runtime.

Comment: Do the functions need to be `static`?

Comment: Isn't it known? This looks just like overloading a function but instead of different parameter it is different value of the parameter.

Comment: I want it to be static but If there isn't a way to make it with static I could use non-static.

Comment: @Vektor007, why do you want two functions with the same name? Could it be one function with different return types?

Comment: @Vektor007 `overloading a function but instead of different parameter it is different value of the parameter` That's not possible in C++, see for example [Overloading by return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568852/overloading-by-return-type).

Comment: I could but I thought It would look better. I am working on a library and I want the function names to be as simple as possible even if that gives me a bit more work. Plus I think it would look better.

Comment: @Vektor007 It won't be simpler in this case as someone has to provide the booleans at compile time. To the user, it's just as much code to provide the boolean to force the overload but more ambiguous. Most people familiar with C++ would expect a function to always return the same type, so this will more likely just confuse them or be a mental obstacle.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You have to store the result somewhere, and you can't store an `int` and a `string` into the same variable, so choosing the return type at runtime is useless anyway.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, you could with a union, which could be beneficial in very specific cases. Although, it probably shouldn't be used in a library boundary without a very good justification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is not about having two different functions but if you wanted the function to return a different type depending on the bool value using [boost::any](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/any.html).

```
boost::any function(int a, int b, const bool c) {
    std::string str = "Hello world!";
    int num = 10;

    if ( c ) {
        return boost::any(num);
    } else {
        return boost::any(str);
    }
}
```

This would use the third parameter in the function in order to decide which return you should do. Depending on how big function is this might be a worse solution but if you really wanted to use a boolean as a parameter I believe this should work.

Docs: [Boost](https://www.boost.org/)

Related question to this answer: [Function which returns an unknown type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358427/function-which-returns-an-unknown-type)

Comment: So there is a way to do it after all. Thanks.

Comment: @Vektor007 I was unsure if you wanted multiple functions or only one! I would recommend reading some of the documentation though since there were some bugs I believe.

Comment: I made two functions because I didn't know that I could do it with one. I will read the documentation. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah I believe you were on the correct way when doing two functions, but I believe they need different parameters if you want to call the same one! Or as with this solution. Good luck on your journey! :D

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function template and add specializations for the different return types. Then you could use the `bool` argument as a template parameter:

```
template<bool>
auto function(int, int);

template<>
auto function<true>(int a, int b)
{
    // ...
    return int{};
}

template<>
auto function<false>(int a, int b)
{
    // ...
    return std::string{};
}
```

The functions would then be called like this:

```
int a = function<true>(1,2);
std::string b = function<false>(1,2);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Fk4kGi).

Note the important caveat that the `bool` parameter must be known at compile time, and can't be a run time argument.

While this technique will work, do be aware that this will confuse a lot of c++ programmers. They usually expect a function to always return a particular type.

More relevant to your question; this is not actually going to make the code much more readable. Instead, having separate named functions is probably a more readable approach:

```
int int_function(int a, int b);
std::string str_function(int a, int b);
```

which could be called like this:

```
int a = int_function(1,2);
std::string b = str_function(1,2);
```

Comment: +1 for the last sentence. This isn't really different from using different function names to begin with.

Comment: Thank you. It won't look as I expected it but I think this is as close as possible to what I wanted.

Comment: @dxiv that's true. But OP seems to want this particular "feature", so just showing a reasonable way of getting to it :)

Comment: @Vektor007 I'd still suggest against this unless you have a really good use-case. Often times when people find clever ways to make it look better, it's actually just more confusing for people that are used to the common convention. It would be a bit confusing returning two different types from the same function, unless they share the same interface. I think you should consider just having different names, as in this case, it won't even be more verbose (actually less verbose)